# Как ограничить повторение цикла foreach?

Tags: php, foreach

Появилась нужда ограничить цикл foreach, чтобы он повторял 3 раза действие.

Код:

```
<?php foreach ($info as $data): ?>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <article>
                                <figure class="overlay overlay-1 hover-scale rounded mb-5"><a href="#"> <img src="<?= $data['image']; ?>" alt="" /></a>
                                    <figcaption>
                                        <h5 class="from-top mb-0">Читать дальше</h5>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                                <div class="post-header">
                                    <div class="post-category text-line">
                                        <a href="#" class="hover" rel="category"><?= $data['theme'] ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.post-category -->
                                    <h2 class="post-title h3 mt-1 mb-3"><a class="link-dark" href="#"><?= $data['heading'] ?></a></h2>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.post-header -->
                                <div class="post-footer">
                                    <ul class="post-meta mb-0">
                                        <li class="post-date"><i class="uil uil-calendar-alt"></i><span><?= $data['date'] ?></span></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <!-- /.post-meta -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.post-footer -->
                            </article>
                            <!-- /article -->
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Как мне это сделать? Помогите)**

Comment: Почему бы не выбрать сразу только 3 записи из хранилища, а не костылять ограничениями в цикле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему, ограничив вывод записей из базы данных, благодаря LIMIT 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach ($info as $index => $data): ?>
<?
 if($index > 2) break; 
?>
```

Comment: Это только при условии, что у него не ассоциативный массив, в ином случае нужна переменная итерации внешняя.